# JXA iTerm Automation - Wait for command to finish

Tags: javascript-automation

I'm trying to use JXA to automated iTerm.

I want to compile some UI code in "watch mode" in the first tab. **After the library is compiled the first time** (and a dist/ folder is created), I want a second tab to open and run some other code which is dependant on the output of the first. In other words, I need the second tab to wait for the first to finish.

As far as JXA automation of iTerm, I cannot find any way for one tab to wait for another.

Every example I've found involves opening several tabs and launching parallel processes in these tabs.

[Here's an example](https://github.com/knrz/iterm-workspace/blob/master/bootstrap-iterm-workspace)

The best I could think of it using some form of setInterval and checking iTerm's `session.isProcessing` (which I found in the docs through Script Editor > Window > Library), but even that just gives some weird errors as if isProcessing is not supposed to be read:

`Error: Can't convert types`

```
    function timer(repeats, func, delay) {
        const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2, -1);
        args.unshift(this);

        const boundFunc = func.bind.apply(func, args);
        const operation = $.NSBlockOperation.blockOperationWithBlock(boundFunc);
        const timer = $.NSTimer.timerWithTimeIntervalTargetSelectorUserInfoRepeats(
            delay / 1000, operation, 'main', null, repeats
        );
        $.NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop.addTimerForMode(timer, "timer");
        return timer;
    }

    function invalidate(timeoutID) {
        timeoutID.invalidate
    }

    const setTimeout = timer.bind(undefined, false)
    const setInterval = timer.bind(undefined, true)
    const clearTimeout = invalidate
    const clearInterval = invalidate

    const terminal = Application('iTerm')
    terminal.includeStandardAdditions = true

    const window = terminal.currentWindow()
    let tab = window.currentTab()
    let session = tab.currentSession();

    setInterval(function() {
        console.log('isProcessing', session.isProcessing);
    }, 500);

    session.write({ text: 'ng build my-angular-lib --watch' });

    //WAIT HERE

    let tab2 = window.createTabWithDefaultProfile();
    let session2 = tab2.currentSession();
    session2.write({ text: 'npm link my-angular-lib && ng serve' });
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but did you consider introducing the concept of resource-lock which might help you tackle the situation?

Comment: I’m new to JXA, I dont know of such a thing.

Comment: I too have no idea of it. Maybe you can explore the [Mutex-Promise](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/mutex-promise) until you get something more meaningful.

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is to debug the full structure of `session` and `tab`.
Maybe the information is there under a different field.

I would try to serialize/stringify the whole object to JSON and print in on the console.

Something like:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(session) )
```